# Getting repeat values after copying 2-3 items to clipboard in android?

Tags: android, clipboard, samsung-mobile

I am using clipboard code like below in my app.Everything is working fine if i copy one item at a time.But when we copy 2-3 items one after other and paste somewhere it starts retrieving repeated past value from clipboard rather than the current value.After googling a lot i came to know that its a problem with Samsung phones and i need to clear clipboard history for that.But i could not find any way to clear clipboard history.

```
Public void CopyToClipboard {

  int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
  StatusEntity obj=getItem(pos);
  ClipboardManager clipmanager= (ClipboardManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  ClipData clip=ClipData.newPlainText("data",obj.getStatus());
  clipmanager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copied to clipboard", 1000).show();
}
```

Hoping that anyone of you can help me regarding this .Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it myself.It was a problem with the tag......i have changed it to value Like below and its working fine now.

```
package com.gippy.status99;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StatusEntity> {
Context context;String copytext;int id;

    public StatusAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<StatusEntity> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Only create view if convertView is null
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_list_item,parent,false);
            }
                TextView txtCategory=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);     
                StatusEntity obj=getItem(position);
                txtCategory.setText(obj.getStatus());

                Button  btn_copy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_copy);
                btn_copy.setTag(txtCategory.getText().toString());
                btn_copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Get the saved value


                    String item = (String) v.getTag();
                    ClipboardManager clipmanager= (ClipboardManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    clipmanager.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), clipmanager.getPrimaryClip().toString(),1000).show();
//                  ClipData clip=ClipData.newPlainText("data",obj.getStatus());
                    ClipData clip=ClipData.newPlainText("data",item);
                    clipmanager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),item,1000).show();
//                  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Copied to clipboard", 1000).show();
                  }
                });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

And it is solved.